# Detect with javascript if user's machine is using 12 hour clock (am/pm) or 24 clock (military time) no matter the locale

Tags: javascript, time

I have a web app with large number of US users (locale en_US), but many of those (say half) use 24 hour time setting on their machines, and I know the en_US default is 12 hour time. How can I detect their settings so as to show them the correct time display?

`Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language,  { hour: 'numeric' }).resolvedOptions().hourCycle` is always `h12` for en_US no matter the user's settings. (and doesn't work in IE11)

`toLocaleTimeString()` works for IE11 (it pulls the computer's settings) but not Edge/Chrome/FF (they always show 12h time)

Comment: Is this even a machine setting?

Comment: If you find a way - please tag me!

I'm in Israel, my system is 24hr, `new Date()` shows up as 24hr, `new Date().toLocaleString()` should show 24hr yet it shows AMPM, and so does `new Date().toLocaleString([])` which is supposed to show what I want not what Chrome thinks...

Comment: @Bergi it is a machine setting, in different places per OS, but for Windows 10, it is in Control Panel --> Clock and Region --> Change date, time, or number formats.

Comment: @iAmOren Israel's Locale `he-IL` is default 24hr, so `new Date().toLocaleTimeString("he-IL")` shows time in 24hr, regardless of machine setting (except in IE, which seems to be the only browser that pulls the machine setting for the default method)

Comment: But I don't like the date format, that's why I use `en-IL`.
No offence, but IE does not exist for me... :)